# How do I read this xml File?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I have this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parameters>
    <parameters 
        registerLink="linkValue" 
        TextBox.name="nameValue" 
    />
</parameters>
```

I want to print off "LinkValue" and "nameValue" by code:

```
 Console.WriteLine("registerLink: " + registerLink);
 Console.WriteLine("TextBox.name: " + TextBox.name);
```

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest LINQ to XML, but I'm not 100% the XML you posted is well-formed or valid, as there is no root element.

Comment: @Tim - the root element is `<parameters>`.

Comment: @MetroSmurf - Yes, that is your first element.  The child element is also named `<parameters>` with attributes, and I think that will make your XML invalid.

Comment: @Tim - As long as there is a single root, then as long as everything is well-formed, the naming doesn't matter. (admittedly, I didn't look that up ;)

Comment: @MetroSmurf - I just tested this, and it does indeed work.  I stand corrected.  I guess an old dog can learn new tricks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest API is XLinq (System.Xml.Linq)

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
// This should be parameters/parameter, i follow the question with parameters/parameters
var par = doc.Element("parameters").Element("parameters");  
registerLink = par.Attribute("registerLink").Value;  // string
```

Comment: You could also return an anonymous type, thought that is probably overkill for this.

Comment: And if OP's posted XML is correct, it won't work as they have `<paramters><parameters...` - no root element.

Comment: @Tim - your right but by avoiding Descendants() it still ought to work. Editing the 2nd name.

Comment: @Tim - just checked but using XDocument is indeed essential here.

Comment: agreed on XDocument - but I'm not sure how that relates to my comments?

Comment: My Element().Element() code doesn't work with XElement.Load (because the top Element then _is_ the outer `<parameters>`). I tend to favor XDocument-less code.

Comment: Got it - I had to look at your edits.  I do a lot with XML to LINQ using XDocument, so my mind just automatically put it in there when it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your could use an xml reader like this one

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Once you have a working sample look here to find out how to open an xml reader from a file stream. File must be located in project directory

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548

Once you have that done you can add an open file dialog box to find any file on the computer and even validate the .xml extension and more.

Edit: As you can see in the comments below, Hanks solution is better, faster, and easier. My solution would only be useful if you have huge xml files with tons of data. You may still be interested in the file dialog box as well.

Comment: Sorry @HenkHolterman but I am only giving an answer based on my experience. If you know more about the subject, I would love to know why it is wrong. I would also like to know why your solution is better. I use this sight to learn and share what I have learned with other people. I did not intend to proclaim my solution was best just that it is possible. Constructive criticism is welcome.

Comment: Write out the necessary code - it's complicated and verbose. XmlReader is useful to handle huge Xml files, but very rarely in other cases.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thank you for the insightful and helpful information. I appreciate it as I am sure others who were unaware do as well. I have updated my post to reflect this information.